# Ubuntu 16.04 KDE plasma can't find any applications

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

I installed latest KDE plasma on Ubuntu 16.04 which is available in backports PPA. When I open applications menu I can't see any applications, I can't open even Files app (when I click on some folder it asks me to select which app to use to open that folder, but the list is empty).
Also my CPU is at 100% all the time so I assume it's indexing files, but even after an hour of waiting it doesn't show any apps and CPU is stil at 100%.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: As a temporary measure to end the CPU madness, open `top` and kill the process for `baloo-file-extractor`. Sometimes, the indexer, baloo, can get into a loop. You can restrict what baloo indexes. See if https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72286-My-first-experience-of-baloo-going-wild helps. I don't know why your launcher is empty. Also, when you say you "installed KDE Plasma", what was the exact command?

Comment: If you installed `plasma-desktop`, that wouldn't bring in Dolphin which is Kubuntu's file manager. Install `kubuntu-desktop` without deleting anything: it will pull in whatever is left out and may, possibly, fix your indexing issue. Note that mixing desktop environments can result in unexpected things happening. I suggest doing a clean install of whatever you want rather than mixing things.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for your reply, I did install kubuntu-desktop, during installation some error poped up, I can't remember which one, then I restarted computer, execute apt-get update and that fixed the error. After I booted into Plasma session I could use the desktop but can't see any applications

Comment: `apt-get update` by itself shouldn't fix anything, AFAICT. It needs to be followed up with at least `apt-get upgrade`.